# Ontouch on Parent layout and getting child click event

Tags: android

I have a `FrameLayout` and i registered `onTouchEvent()` on it . And its working great . But i have a `Button` inside that layout on which a `onClick()` event should get called but it is never gets called. Cause the Parent view getting the Toch state. Suggest me a better Option to do that

Here is the Xml

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/localView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/userCamWidth"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/userCamHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/localViewStub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout="@layout/local_videoview" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/switchCameraToggle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toggleIconSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toggleIconSize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLarge"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginLarge"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_switch_camera_sm"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
             />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/cameraOff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

and Here is the onToch

```
 camContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX = camContainer.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = camContainer.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float moveX=event.getRawX() + dX;
                    float moveY=event.getRawY() + dY;
                    if (moveX < 0) {
                        moveX = 0;
                    }
                    if (moveX > screenX) {
                        moveX = screenX;
                    }
                    if (moveY < 0) {
                        moveY = 0;
                    }
                    if (moveY > screenY) {
                        moveY = screenY;
                    }
                        camContainer.animate()
                                .x(moveX)
                                .y(moveY)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Cause get all of the focus of the `FrameLayout`.